# Using Factory Girl with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

I have set up Rspec with a rails4 app however the tests are returning:

```
Failure/Error: user = Factory(:user)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `Factory' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_4::Nested_1:0x007fa08c0d8a98>
```

Seems like I'm including FactoryGirl incorrectly.  I've tried a couple of variations but I can't get it to work.

My Spec Helper:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'factory_girl_rails'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }


# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
  config.include Capybara::DSL, :type => :request
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

gem file:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', :require => false  # as per sugestion on SO.  Without the require false also fails
  gem "capybara"
end
```

my spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Create Event" do
  describe "Log in and create an event" do
    it "Allows creation of individual events" do
      user = Factory(:user)
      visit "/"
    end
  end
end
```

and in /spec/factories/users.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |f|
    f.email "provider@example.com"
    f.password "password"
  end
end
```

How can i get going with factory girl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a user using FactoryGirl:

```
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

This will use everything you defined in the factory to create the user.  You can also override any value, or specify additional values at the same time.  For example:

```
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, username: 'username', email: 'different-email@example.com)
```

Alternatively you can use `FactoryGirl.build(:user, ...)` where you want to make use of the factory to build an instance but not actually save it to the database.

Comment: Ah, yes thats it.  I was following the rails cast & as the comments point out the syntax has changed a bit.  thanks Graeme.  http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test?view=comments#comment_158161

Answer (score 7):

Given that you have included:

```
config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
```

In your RSpec configure block, I'm guessing that the syntax you're looking for is:

```
user = create(:user)
```

or:

```
user = build(:user)
```

Comment: Neat.  Been using FactoryGirl for ages and I didn't know about this new shorter syntax.

Comment: This is cool.  I wasn't trying for that but I will use it from now. thanks.  (shame i can't tick both answers)

Comment: `user = build(:user)` # Returns a User instance that's not saved


`user = create(:user)` # Returns a saved User instance